# defining query string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

This query run directly in PostgreSQL panel but when i define in my code same Query , query string get me error ,How to define in proper manner in asp.net

My code is :-

```
  string sQuery = "SELECT 'Inspection Completed' as "MCD Status" ,COUNT(*) as "Number of Count" FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Inspection Completed' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%' union 
  SELECT 'Pending' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Pending' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'
  union
  SELECT 'Approved' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Approved' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'
  union
  SELECT 'Rejected' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Rejected' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'";
```

Comment: Whats the error? To me it looks like you are using double quotes without escaping them.

Comment: how can i define it in proper manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to escape double quotes (").

If you need more information around string literals take a look at the official Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Try the following:

```
string sQuery = "SELECT 'Inspection Completed' as \"MCD Status\" ,COUNT(*) as 
\"Number of Count\" FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Inspection Completed' AND 
name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%' union 
SELECT 'Pending' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Pending' AND 
name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'
union
SELECT 'Approved' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Approved' AND 
name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'
union
SELECT 'Rejected' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Rejected' AND 
name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have problem with special character escaping.

```
string sQuery = "SELECT 'Inspection Completed' as \"MCD Status\" ,COUNT(*) as \"Number of Count\" FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Inspection Completed' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%' union 
  SELECT 'Pending' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Pending' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'
  union
  SELECT 'Approved' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Approved' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'
  union
  SELECT 'Rejected' , COUNT(*) FROM ud_document WHERE status = 'Rejected' AND name_owning_agency like '%MZONE%'";
```

Comment: Thank you for help Necvetanov